# send notification to multiple user with they token in fcm

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification to multiple users (with their token that stored in database) .

for the some reason i can't use [Topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) in fcm , now i want add some users to the specific category in my database and send notification to that users exist on category .

Now i want to know is `firebase cloud messaging` have a this option to send notification to the multiple device with their token ? and if it have is it affect on speed or ... ?

Comment: According to this, it has the option:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

Comment: Do you use Firebase console or your own server?

Comment: @MehulJoisar i use my server

Comment: @GáborNádai this article used for topic messaging , i need to token solution

Comment: Use `registration_ids` instead of `to`. AFAIK, it doesn't have any affect on speed. However, there is a limit of 1000 tokens per request when you use `registration_ids`.

Comment: @kiana: you should use comma separated values inside `registration_ids` parameter while posting on FCM.